# Self Learning Quantum Mechanics and QFT, how to?

Tags: soft-question, education

I've searched the board and several threads were found, but they all were very old and closed.
I'm interested in learning and understanding quantum mechanics, after that possibly also QFT. I have Calculus I and Linear Algebra I background (studying economics). I won't get into more advanced math at college until I start my masters in financial mathematics (and even then the math will probably be different). So, self learning will be the way.
I've found 2 Quantum Mechanics books:

1. Griffiths Introduction
2. Landau and Lifshitz

Math in both books was beyond me as I have no knowledge in Diff. Equations, vector calculus, etc. So, I've picked M. Boas book "Mathematical Methods for Physical Sciences" and started to work with it.

The question is, should I wait with reading QM books until I finish Boas? If I finish Boas, will I have enough Math. proficiency to understand QM and QFT? If no, what else will I need and what books are recommended. Is there any physics I should understand before reading QM and QFT stuff? I have some knowledge of Newtonian mechanics, but in its easier form (not analytical mechanics).

Would be grateful for any advice.

Comment: I would just start reading Griffiths, and use boas as you go to fill in the gaps. Griffiths is a good introductory book because he develops math along the way, either in the reading or as part of a problem. L & L will expect you to have a pretty tight understanding of the math and you may find yourself spending a long time on a problem only to look at the answer and find that it used a completely foreign mathematical concept.

Comment: I don't want to discourage you but QM, and especially QFT, are quite mathematical. From what I have seen, the maths you get in economics (even in economical engineering)  is _way_ too little. Griffith's book is actually one of the easiest books on QM I have seen so far... You should at least first work your way through something like Adams and Essex Calculus book and a decent linear algebra course before you get started on QM. I think it would also be best if you study a bit of classical mechanics first, too, or at least an introductory to it; especially some wave mechanics.

Comment: Not sure why the question should be put on hold, since there are many examples of questions asking for useful references to make use of in particular subjects.

Comment: Thanks for your input, guys. I'm currently working on LA in Boas book. I'll go through ODE and PDE and start with Griffiths.